# Saving client certificate passphrase for Git over HTTPS?

Tags: git, curl, https, client-certificates

I'm trying to use a remote Git repository that only provides access over HTTPS using client certificates.  I've (finally...) gotten it working, but now I'm running into a minor issue -- every time I touch the remote, Git prompts me for the certificate passphrase.  Obviously, this gets old fast.

If I were using SSH, I could follow the [official guide](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/) to provide credentials with `ssh-agent`. But, AFAICT there's no way to have Git (or Curl, which is the library I think Git stubs out to under the hood) use ssh-agent to access credentials for an HTTPS connection.  I'd also be fine with tying either of those two to `gnome-keyring` for the passphrase, but I haven't found anything about either approach online.

Can it be done?  I *might* be able to talk the server admin into turning on SSH access, which I'm sure would sort me right out, but in the meantime it'd be easier if I could get it to save the passphrase for HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 2013: This was added in git 1.8.0.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385690/how-to-use-git-with-gnome-keyring-integration) explains how to use the new gnome-keyring credential helper.

Comment: I asked another question because it looks like the gnome-keyring credential helper *might* only work for storing username/password, not client certificates.