# How to use git with gnome-keyring integration

Tags: git, gnome

Git 1.8.0 supports integration with gnome-keyring.

http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Git-1-8-0-can-access-Windows-and-GNOME-keyrings-1733879.html

After reading the docs about the git credentials helpers: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html

I was not able to find a way to use this new feature. How can I integrate it?
I'm using Archlinux with git installed from Archlinux's repository. (git 1.8.0)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Git 1.8.0 comes with gnome-keyring support but the binary needs to be compiled for your platform.

This is what solved it for me in Archlinux:

```
$ sudo pacman -S libgnome-keyring
$ cd /usr/share/git/credential/gnome-keyring
$ make
$ git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/git/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring
```

@VonC solution was close, but the git config command should point to the executable. That's why it was not working for me.

Comment: I have reformatted my answer to reflect your conclusion. I have built it (it wasn't build by default in my git 1.8 distro) and tested it this morning. It does work.

Comment: If you are getting `Package gnome-keyring-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.` you are missing the dev libraries for gnome-keyring.  On Ubuntu these are available with `apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev`.  Also, I had to download the git contrib repo manually from https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib and put it in /usr/share/git-core/.  These files are no longer included with a default git install, at least using the official git-core ubuntu ppa.

Comment: This pretty well explains why the aur package `git-credential-gnomekeyring` is gone, too bad that in AUR there's no such information.

Comment: On ubuntu I have no git folder in `/usr/share/`...only gitweb and git-core. But I am on Git 1.7.9. Could that be why...?

Comment: As of 2017 on Arch, simply installing `libgnome-keyring` is sufficient (at least if you are using gnome).

Comment: `libgnome-keyring` [is now deprecated](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring) and requires one of the `org.freedesktop.secrets` packages to be installed. Of which the new `gnome-keyring` is one.

Answer (score 228):

@marcosdsanchez's answer is for Arch (which answers the original question) but I'm on Ubuntu.  For git >= 2.11:

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

For git < 2.11:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring
```

Comment: I was hesitant to do this at first, but I did finally and it works perfectly. As the [docs for gitcredentials](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/gitcredentials.html) say, you might also want to do `git help -a | grep credential-` and see if you have other helpers installed. Ones that come by default are `credential-cache` (remember password for some time after you enter it, 15 minutes by default), and `credential-store` (just store the password in plaintext on an unencrypted file on disk, `~/.git-credentials` by default).

Comment: Works in actual Debian testing (jessie) too!

Comment: Could anyone explain why this needs to be compiled manually and is not available by default through a package?

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS!

Comment: Verified in Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: just had to do `chmod 0755 git-credential-gnome-keyring` to add execution permission to others than root

Comment: Worked for BunsenLabs 8.2

Comment: After the first step, tried the second and found nothing but osxkeychain inside /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credentials/. :(

Comment: I don't know what is this doing, but it works like magic! @Xubuntu_14.04.4

Comment: * Ubuntu 16.10   

Tried running this:    
$ sudo make   


Got the error:    
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.     


Then I tried this:   
$ sudo make git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring    

Got the error:
make: unrecognized option '--global'
Usage: make [options] [target] ...


I have a feeling this will also work on Ubuntu 16.10, but I do not know how could I make it work.

Comment: Sounds like it came with the binary already? Try just `git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-cred‌​ential-gnome-keyring`

Comment: @lanoxx: See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740739 .  Looks like it's just a lack of maintainer time/attention.

Comment: Still valid for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Am I the only person who can't compile this on Ubuntu 16.04??

`git-credential-gnome-keyring.c:29:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

`dpkg -l|egrep "libgnome-keyring-dev|libglib2.0-dev"
ii  libglib2.0-dev                              2.48.2-0ubuntu1                                    amd64        Development files for the GLib library
ii  libgnome-keyring-dev                        3.12.0-1build1                                     amd64        Development files for GNOME keyring service`

Comment: Once I set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, `git-credential-gnome-keyring` built.

Comment: Tried and tried but only ever get `CRITICAL **: Error communicating with gnome-keyring-daemon` when attempting to pull from master, and am prompted for my creds.  Ubuntu 14.04, git 2.16.1.

Comment: Used this but instead of compiling it in the folder specified above I copied that folder to ~/bin, then ran make (without sudo) inside that folder. I could now do git config --global credential.helper ~/bin/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring  to start using it.

Comment: (Partially @lanoxx) Actually, some distros like Fedora and Arch Linux do provide the compiled `git-credential-libsecret` binary by default. See [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585496/error-when-using-git-credential-helper-with-gnome-keyring-as-sudo/40312117#40312117).

Comment: That solution does not seem to work anymore for me on Ubuntu 19.10. `E: Unable to locate package libgnome-keyring-dev`

Comment: `sudo make` in the corresponding directory results in: `No package 'gnome-keyring-1' found`. The latter package does neither exist. `gnome-keyring` does not seem to be an option.

Comment: @Mario You need to follow the instructions for `git >= 2.11` on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: For a nice clean installation: Mark temporary dev dependencies for auto-removal with `sudo apt-mark auto libsecret-1-dev libglib2.0-dev` if you won't need them after compilation. After make, move the compiled program `sudo mv git-credential-libsecret /usr/local/bin/git-credential-libsecret` and then remove the `.o` file generated with `sudo make clean`. This way, you can simply do `sudo git config --system credential.helper libsecret`. It will also be listed under `git help -a | grep credential-`.

Comment: +1 :) Btw if you use `sudo make -C /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring` you can get rid of the `cd`, save a line, and not touch the user's cwd.

Comment: Debian [no longer provides `libgnome-keyring` or `libgnome-keyring-dev`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892359) so `git-credential-gnome-keyring` is no longer an option. However, they recommend using `libsecret`, which exists right next door in `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret`... going to try it out.

Comment: I needed to install also `gnome-keyring` package on Debian buster.

Comment: This worked for Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I had already tried the gnome-keyring approach which didn't work as it is outdated now. Not sure if that earlier installation was required, but I only had to enter my credentials one more time after using this solution.

Comment: It works well for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with git 2.34.1

Answer (score 29):

Update Q4 2016:

- Unix, Mac (Git 2.11+)

  ```
    git config --global credential.helper libsecret
  ```

(See "[Error when using Git credential helper with `gnome-keyring`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/6309)")

- Windows:

  ```
    git config --global credential.helper manager
  ```

(See "[How to sign out in Git Bash console in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)": That is **[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)** using the latest [**Microsoft Git Credential Manager for Windows**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows))

Reminder: `libgnome-keyring` is specific to GNOME and is:

- deprecated since [January 2014](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2014-January/msg01585.html)
- completely removed with [Git 2.41 (Q2 2023)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/6309)

---

Original answer (2012)

Credential Helpers, for Windows, Mac and Unix platforms, have been introduced first in ["git-credential-helper" repo](https://github.com/pah/git-credential-helper), **which now has been included in git distro**:

> This repository contains the set of Git credential helpers (`gitcredentials`(7)) that are part of `git` (or meant to be contributed in the future).

```
$ git clone git://github.com/pah/git-credential-helper.git
$ BACKEND=gnome-keyring      # or any other backend
$ cd git-credential-helper/$BACKEND
$ make
$ cp git-credential-$BACKEND /path/to/git/crendential
```

When built, it would be installed in `/path/to/git/credential` directory.

> To use this backend, you can add it to your (global) Git configuration by setting

(here for Unix):

```
git config --global credential.helper /path/to/git/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring
```

---

Note for Windows:

I suppose you could make a program running on Windows and calling a library like "[pypi keyring 0.10](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring)".
But that is the back-end, and you don't use it directly from Git.

What you are using is a "credential helper" (which, in turn, will call [any credential API it wants on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/287442/is-there-something-like-gnome-keyring-for-windows7)).

[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) provides such a helper (as an executable called... `github`), and can store your credentials for the duration of the Windows session.
Launch a shell from that "GitHub for Windows" windows, and you will see, typing "`git config --system -l`":

```
C:\Users\VonC\Documents\GitHub\test [master +2 ~0 -0 !]> git config --system -l
credential.helper=!github --credentials
```

The `credential.helper=!github --credentials` part will call the credential helper '`github`'.

```
$ git config [--global] credential.helper $BACKEND
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. The answer should be *nix only.

Comment: @marcosdsanchez ok, I have edited my answer to include a setup and usage of gnome-keyring on Unix with Git.

Comment: I want to use git's 1.8.0 feature, which is already there. Not third party code. Thanks.

Comment: @marcosdsanchez then you need to compile https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring (which is packaged with git). Once compiled, you would install and use it as illustrated in my answer.

Comment: I guess there's no binary built-in?

Answer (score 21):

Update October 2018

GNOME has deprecated libgnome-keyring and replaced it with libsecret. Commit https://github.com/git/git/commit/87d1353a6a added a new credential helper /usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-libsecret.

`git config --global credential.helper libsecret`

Comment: Probably, this should be a comment on any gnome-keyring based answer here.

Comment: Agree, `gnome-keyring` based answers should be edited accordingly. Maybe just exclude the whole option. That didn't work at all for me on Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone on Fedora, I edited James Ward's answer slightly:

```
sudo yum install libgnome-keyring-devel
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring
```

Comment: I'm confused, isn't this already included with the git packages? What is this file then within the fc19 package, git-1.8.3.1-1.fc19.x86_64. There's this file here: `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-gnome-keyring`.

Comment: In Fedora 21, git 2.1.0, you can simply do: `git config --global credential.helper gnome-keyring`

Comment: Fedora 32: `sudo dnf install git-credential-libsecret` then `git config --global credential.helper libsecret`

Comment: This method is outdated to now

Answer (score 8):

Just add these two lines to your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[credential]
    helper = gnome-keyring
```

Next time you are asked for a password by Git, the entered password will be saved to Gnome Keyring (you can see this with `seahorse` tool), and you won't be asked for the password again afterwards.

This assumes that your Git version is sufficiently new (like 2.1.0) and you are under <strike>Linux</strike> Fedora, RHEL or CentOS. For older versions or other OSs/distros check out the other answers.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04: `git: 'credential-gnome-keyring' is not a git command.`

Comment: @Saibot: whoops, you're right. Looks like Fedora/RHEL provide this, but Ubuntu doesn't. So the answer by James Ward (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528360/2148773) is better in that case.

Comment: In RHEL you need to install git-gnome-keyring if not already done.

Answer (score 4):

On Fedora you need to **install**

```
$ sudo dnf install git-credential-libsecret
```

and edit your **git configuration** to use the credential helper.

```
[credential]
    helper = /usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-libsecret
```

FYI the `libsecret` package has recently been split up, see [post from @rugk](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/attention-git-credential-libsecret-for-storing-git-passwords-in-the-gnome-keyring-is-now-an-extra-package/18275?u=rugk). That's why users need to reinstall this package.

Answer (score 3):

Some distributions do come with this integration as an installation package, without requiring any compilation. Depending on your version of GNOME, you will need to install either `gnome-keyring` or `libsecret` versions of the package, something like `git-credential-gnome-keyring` (OpenSUSE Leap 42.3).

However, this in itself will not enable Git integration with the GNOME Keyring automatically. You must still configure Git to use this method of credential storage:

```
git config --global credential.helper gnome-keyring # If you installed git-credential-gnome-keyring
git config --global credential.helper libsecret     # If you installed git-credential-libsecret
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.10, the `gnome-keyring` option does no more work for me, but James Ward's instruction using `libsecret` still works well. I was, however, confused by the recommendation to use `gnome-keyring` given here: https://github.com/timhughes/git-credential-libsecret

Comment: `libsecret` (or what `find /usr -iname git-credential-libsecret` gives) is the right option in Gentoo Linux. Note that `dev-vcs/git` must be emerged with `USE=gnome-keyring`.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying [the answer for Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528360/7020378) on a *headless server* and I got the following errors when entering my token:

```
Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login

store failed: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
```

Here is the solution that worked for me on the headless server (see  https://keyring.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-keyring-on-headless-linux-systems):

- First I ran the same commands as in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528360/7020378) to set `git-credential-libsecret` as the `credential.helper`:

```sh
# You may also first install gnome-keyring if not installed
sudo apt install gnome-keyring
sudo apt install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

- Then, whenever I start a session where I will make use of the credentials (e.g. commands like `git push`), I run:

```sh
dbus-run-session -- sh  # Replace 'sh' with whatever shell you use.
gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock
# Enter your token here, then hit Enter, then Ctrl+d
# You might clean the terminal display with Ctrl+l for security reasons
```

This runs a D-Bus session inside which the I can run for example `git push` and the likes with automatic authentication.

Comment: I feel this answer comes close, but opening a new shell process and starting a daemon just to run my git commands is almost as much hassle as just typing in the credentials every time. Can't you run the dbus without a new shell process?

Comment: @jiggunjer That's a good point. What I personally do is that I am working inside a Tmux session on the remote machine. This way I only had to run the above commands once: every time I resume my work on the remote machine, I reattach the Tmux session, where the daemon is still running.

Answer (score 2):

Arch Linux's [git package](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/git/) includes git-credential-libsecret (which replaced git-credential-gnome-keyring), so you can run:

```
git config --global credential.helper libsecret
```

---

As an alternative to entering passwords or personal tokens, you can also try [git-credential-oauth](https://github.com/hickford/git-credential-oauth).

> *No more passwords! No more personal access tokens! No more SSH keys!*
>
> A Git credential helper that securely authenticates to GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket and other forges using OAuth.
>
> The first time you push, the helper will open a browser window to authenticate. Subsequent pushes within storage lifetime require no interaction.

This is compatible with any storage helper including git-credential-cache or git-credential-libsecret.

Comment: The pointer to git-credential-oauth is the simplest solution for most users now.