# linux git authentication to TFS git repo

Tags: git, tfs

My group recently setup a new TFS hosted git repository.  I'm able to connect fine, and do everything as expected, except each time it is prompting me for permissions.

I'm running git on a linux box, inside the company firewall, but not associated with the domain.

I did a bit of digging, and didn't see much information on caching my credentials.  Does anyone have any insight on where to store at least my active directory username so I can avoid the prompt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Comment: You should be able to use the credential helper mechanisms in git against TFS; hopefully the above link will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above link provided by Edward, I got this working.  Following the details provided by the following answer was the exact route to take:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528360/87761

I got prompted for my AD credentials once, and then wasn't prompted again.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  Sometimes it takes someone reading the question in a different way than I was asking to get me headed in the right direction.