# Trouble installing a source package from a local file

Tags: r

This seems like it might be a rookie mistake because it probably is.  I have a built source package that I'm trying to install.  It's a local file and I just want to check to make sure it works.  Everything seems to go smoothly, no errors...but also no functions.

```
> dir.create("packageCheck")
> install.packages("Rpackages/saber_0.1.tar.gz",   
                   lib = "packageCheck", repos = NULL)
# * installing *source* package ‘saber’ ...
# ** R
# ** inst
# ** preparing package for lazy loading
# ** help
# *** installing help indices
# ** building package indices
# ** testing if installed package can be loaded
# * DONE (saber)
> list.files("packageCheck")
# [1] "saber"
> list.files("packageCheck/saber")
# [1] "DESCRIPTION" "extdata"     "help"        "html"       
# [5] "INDEX"       "Meta"        "NAMESPACE"   "R"          
> devtools::load_all("packageCheck/saber")
# Loading saber
> library("saber", lib.loc = "packageCheck/saber", logical.return = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
> ls(2)
# character(0)
> ls("package:saber")
# character(0)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note:

```
> version[[1]]
# [1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
> getOption("pkgType")
# [1] "source"
```

Comment: what does `ls(getNamespace('saber'))` return; whats in the namespace file?

Comment: `character(0)` is the return.  The file is two imports and 19 exports.  Do I need to install it to one of `.libPaths()` maybe?

Comment: hm, not sure. It's weird that none of your exports are showing up. does it work if you install it from github?

Comment: That's a separate issue.  I don't really know how to put it on GitHub without losing my mind.  I wrote the package, it's my first one and I'm still learning the ropes. I thought I had [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944387/errors-when-using-rstudios-git-tools) figured out, but today I opened RStudio and it was reverted back to the problem.

Comment: Can you look at the NAMESPACE file **in the package**? Maybe you are generating the NAMESPACE file via `roxygen2`, and it creates an empty file, because you don't have `@export` roxygen flags? It would actually help if you could upload the package tarball (or something minimal if it is private) somewhere, so that we can actually look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering about why the functions are not exported, not about github. For uploading the package, just take the built tarball and upload it to dropbox or even as a github gist if it is not too big. I don't use rstudio, so I can't help you with using git from rstudio. But I bet that the NAMESPACE file in the package is empty. In the built/installed package.

Comment: Or even just create a gist and upload one R source file from your package and the code that you use for building it. Or maybe you build it from rstudio.

Comment: @GaborCsardi - I put three files at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rmscriven/abd7464f686540c507b8)

Comment: Can you include DESCRIPTION as well?

Comment: And your saber.Rproj file? This is the last one, I promise....

Comment: How can I view the contents of that file?

Comment: It is a text file. Any text editor is fine.

Comment: Okie doke.  It's up there too

Comment: OK, I think I can replicate this. Wait a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `devtools::load_all()` is not for loading installed packages. It is meant to be used in the source tree of your package. E.g. if you just say `load_all()` in the source tree of your package, then it should work.

What I guess happens, is that `load_all()` looks for `.R` files to load in the installed package, but there are no `.R` files in installed packages, the R functions are put in a database when you install a package:

```
/tmp/saber (master)$ ls -l packageCheck/saber/R/
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 gaborcsardi  wheel  1056 Jul 25 23:27 saber
-rw-r--r--  1 gaborcsardi  wheel  3317 Jul 25 23:27 saber.rdb
-rw-r--r--  1 gaborcsardi  wheel   246 Jul 25 23:27 saber.rdx
```

So `load_all()` does not find anything to load, but it creates a namespace nevertheless, named `saber`. Then, when you try to load the package with `library()`, the function returns immediately, because it notices that there is a `saber` namespace in the `search()` list, so it assumes that the package was already loaded.

The solution is either to

1. just use `load_all()` and then `reload()` in the source directory of your package, without actually installing it. (You might need to build, I am not sure about that.) This works most of the time.
2. Or just use `library` to load the installed package:

   `library("saber", lib.loc = "packageCheck", logical.return = TRUE)`

   This is somewhat less convenient, because you need to build and install all the time and unloading/reloading a package might fail in R.

Just don't use `load_all()` on the installed package.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Like I said, rookie mistake and a minor one at that.  The reason I chose `load_all()` is because I usually see a `package intalled to filepath` message after an install but not when I did this install. Definitely knowledge for the next run.  Cheers.