# git - Git asking for SSH password every time

Tags: git, ssh

I use SSH to connect to my server (Ubuntu 15.10) where I push and pull to Git repositories.
However, despite installing the `gnome-keyring` with instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385690/how-to-use-git-with-gnome-keyring-integration).

Strangely, the Credential Helper works correctly with repositories I clone from GitHub using HTTPS, but not with my own SSH server.

Comment: What git version are you on? The link you mentioned says it requires git 1.8 (highly doubt this is the issue tho)

Comment: Other possibly related Questions: [Git keeps prompting me for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-a-password) and [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh-to-login-once). Cross site: [How to make git not prompt for passphrase for ssh key? (*on superuser*)](https://superuser.com/q/1010542/910769)

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer here: [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh-to-login-once)

Basically, I had to generate a key pair with `ssh-keygen`, and send it to the server with `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@host`.

`ssh-agent` did the rest of the work for me, remembering my passphrase.

**Edit**

Thanks to [@DigitalRoss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595863/3571248) and [@Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595858/3571248) for their helpful answers.