# Create and return Github token from bash

Tags: bash, github, command-line-interface

The first time we run [`hub`](https://hub.github.com/), it asks for our Github username and password. This is never stored. Instead, `hub` uses it to create a personal access token that gets [saved in your account](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and then it uses that token for subsequent uses.

Is there a way to achieve the same from a `bash` script, without registering an application and all that?

This script will be public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without registering an application

Not exactly, since it is part of the [oauth workflow](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/).

But from a simple shell, you can store your GitHub username and password in a **[credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386417/6309)** like libsecret (Mac) or manager (Windows).

In that case, you won't have to enter said credentials again and you don't have to register anything directly on GitHub.

Comment: “But from a simple shell, you can store your GitHub username and password in a credential helper”. No good, since I wanted to do this as part of setting up a new machine.