# Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h

Tags: jenkins, centos7, github-for-windows

I have installed `jenkins` on my `centos7 server` and tried to build a `maven` build. Created a new maven build job and in `SCM` I was trying to pull the code from `github` but it showed me an error like...

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://github.com/example.git HEAD" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/example.git/'
```

And also I setup an `SSH` public keys to my `github`. I don't know how to solve this. Anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893328/bitbucket-access-keys-can-only-be-used-for-read-only/55469070#55469070

Answer (score 1):

> also I setup an SSH public keys to my github

That would have zero impact on an HTTPS URL: the SSH key is ignored.

Check if you havbe a git credential helper in place which might cache your credentials (GitHub username/password)

```
git config credential.helper
```

For instance, [it could be '`cache`'](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/git-credential-store/).

I would recommend (as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21192134/6309)) to set it to `gnome-keyring`:

```
git config --global credential.helper gnome-keyring
```

Then try again your `git ls-remote`, from command-line:

```
git ls-remote https://<yourUsername>@github.com/<yourUsername>/<yourRepo.git>
```

That should prompt for your GitHub username/password. Once entered, a second `git ls-remote` should not ask again for your credentials.

From there, an SCM process from your Jenkins, as long as said Jenkins runs with your account, should work.