# Bitbucket access keys can only be used for read-only?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

First time using bitbucket, trying to make a first push of my local project to bitbucket.

I managed to create a repository with no issues. After I created a new SSH Key, which I loaded to both Bitbucket and also Pagent (that is running in my windows background).

Still when I try to push my commit to Bitbucket I get the following:

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
>   Pushing to user@bitbucket.user/repository.git
>   repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.
>   Completed with errors, see above.

On Bitbucket -> Project -> Settings -> Access Keys:
It says here, copying and pasting as it is:

> Use access keys to gain read-only access to this repository. Learn more about using SSH keys.

Does this mean I can not use SSH Keys to make a push to the repository? 
PS: I tried all the solutions that were available to sort out this issue, still I get the same error (regenerated the keys, tried both SourceTree or GitShell to make the push, still same error coming up); any other ideas are welcomed

Thanks

Comment: Deployment keys are meant to give read-only access. You want to create and use an account or user SSH key pair instead. On BitBucket, go to `Account -> Security -> SSH Keys` and follow the instructions there.

Comment: @Derek I checked what you suggested and I can see the ssh key I have previously added through Project->Settings->Access Keys. Still same error when I try to push

Comment: I managed to finally make a push through git shell, by creating a new key where you specified (Acc->Security->SSH Keys); still does not seem to want to work with SourceTree

Comment: have you configured with git? and added remote repo url? follow this three steps. 1. git add --all, 2. git commit -am "inital commit" 3. git push -u origin master(depends on the branch name)

Comment: Yes thanks, I managed to do all that in the end after setting a new ssh key for the account not the project and adding it to Pagent. Think the UX/UI is a bit confusing when setting up keys for Bitbucket. As I can see in the Account->Security->SSH Keys the also the key that was created through Bitbucket->Project->Setting->Access Keys; tough as far as I understood, correct me if I am wrong, that the two paths create two different keys with different access levels but still they get bulked under the same list of SSH Keys

Answer (score 1):

> I managed to finally make a push through git shell, by creating a new key where you specified (Acc->Security->SSH Keys); still does not seem to want to work with SourceTree

Check if SourceTree is configured to use the embedded git or the system Git (the latter being the one you have installed. And make sure your SourceTree runs with your account.

The [OP Marin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4090918/marin)  adds in the comments:

> I managed to do all that in the end after setting a new ssh key for the account not the project and adding it to Pagent.
>
> I managed to sort the issue quite quickly after the initial commit and push through Git Shell, I just checked out the repository using SourceTree and it worked (also my account was already linked to SourceTree)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I managed to sort the issue quite quickly after the initial commit and push through Git Shell I just checked out the repository using source tree and it worked (also my account was already linked to SourceTree).

Comment: @Marin Great! I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your ssh-agent is working:

`ssh-add -l`

If you get error just do:

`` eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
ssh-add -l ``