# Jenkins: Git Failed to connect to repository, returned status code 128

Tags: jenkins, github

I'm attempting to clone a remote GitHub enterprise repository and am running into the following error after adding my remote repo's URL to the Git Plugin in my Jenkins configuration:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h https://<<server>>/M/AS.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://<<server>>/M/AS.git/': Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: You must be using proxy. Are you using windows?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893328/bitbucket-access-keys-can-only-be-used-for-read-only/55469070#55469070

Answer (score 2):

Firs of all You Need to setup github with jenkins in below section also

Go to [Github](https://github.com/) --> `click on profile dropdown` --> `settings` --> `devloper settings` --> `personal access token` --> 
`generate new token` --> `select all scopes` --> `copy the token`

Then go to [Jenkins](http://localhost:8080/) --> `manage Jenkins` --> `github settings` --> `add user` --> `Select secret text`--> `paste the token`

> Then Test the git-hub connection by clicking test button If its Successful the Jenkins will ready to clone the GitHub repository

**And also add Webhooks, Integrations & Services in GitHub**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have generated Git API Token in Git repository and added the same in the Jenkins Credentials.
If the is done, I don't think there will be any issue in connecting Git to Jenkins.

Also you can test if your Git server is able to ping your Jenkins server. (If you are running your own Git and Jenkins).

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Check your failed job environment variables.

If there is no environment variable named NO_PROXY, set one in the configuration of your JENKINS job:

```
NO_PROXY=.mycompany.com
```

Here, I assume your GitHub Enterprise has an URL like myserver.mycompany.com (replace (`mycompany.com` by your own)

That will avoid Jenkins trying to access the remote server through the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from a VM, make sure you install the package 'git-core'.

You must have git installed in the machine where jenkins is running

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me it helped a restart for the machine where it was installed Jenkins.