# How can I change the default credentials for Git commit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am committing code using TortoiseGit, but I do not have access to the git repository which am committing I want to use other persons username and password to commit.

Each time I commit, the commit did not happen because it tries to commit using my credential (Current logged in win user).

I want to give the other persons id and password to commit.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

A commit is done locally, and uses local config (`user.name`/`user.email`) which have nothing to do with the authentication used when *pushing* to a remote repo.

So if you are talking about pushing, check your remote url (`git remote -v`): if it is https and Git does not ask you for credential, you probably have [a credential helper caching those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386417/6309).